# Codeigniter row_array content if no row is fetched

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I use codeigniter active record to get data from database.

Assuming a simple query,

```
$query = $this->db->get_where("employees", array("employee_name" => "nightgaunt"));
$row = $query->row_array();
```

I just need to see whether the row exists or not, and if row exists, get employee_id. Does row_array return false or null if no row exists?

I know I can use `$query->num_rows()` but that is not preferred where the number of rows fetched will be in tens of thousands which is exactly my case. Either I get zero rows or 1 - 20,000 rows.

I can use `COUNT` but I am wasting one query just to get the number of rows. I again need to query to get the employee_id.

Update:
My exact scenario is this. I need to track all the quiz submissions to show results for comparison. While a user attempts to take the quiz, I need to send a flag - whether the same user has taken same quiz or not. If taken, I need to send the latest date when it was taken.

Comment: group by employee_name.

Comment: With my scenario, it is not quite simple. But your comment gave me some insight about how it can be done. Thanks!!

Comment: you can set limit to get one row in query then can check number of rows is equal to one. $this->db->get_where("employees", array("employee_name" => "nightgaunt"), 1); if ($query->num_rows() == 1)

Comment: if no `row` found `$query->row_array()` will return `an empty array` and then you can check `if ($query->row_array()){ /* not empty */} else {/* empty */}`

Comment: The answer I wanted. Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no row was found, `row_array` returns empty array.

If you put empty array in if statement it will be false.

```
$a = array();
if($a) {
  // it won't run
}
```

Reference: http://www.blueshoes.org/en/developer/php_cheat_sheet